# How to use Service Account Credentials (in json format) to access my gmail account using GMail API in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, gmail-api, service-accounts

I have created a service account and also obtained a credentials file in JSON format. 
Can somebody point me to a sample **VB.Net** code for using this credentials file to access my email account?

I did search extensively but I keep getting references to C# code, .p12 file only

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to familiarize yourself with Stack Overflow. You have not provided enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).